# Nearest Neighbour analysis between points in 2 tables utilizing with distances set along specific polyline roads

Tags: mapinfo, analysis, road, proximity

I'm trying to do a Nearest Neighbor analysis between points in 2 tables utilizing with distances set along specific polyline road files I have. I am attempting to determine the most cost effective way to undertake works for a local council. I'm using Mapinfo and can get nearest neighbor analysis but it is just straight line distance not using the roads.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are really after is some routing software. Take a look at RouteFinder for MapInfo @ [www.routeware.dk](http://www.routeware.dk)

Besides using some bespoke software I think the only other option is to attempt to write a routine yourself using MapBasic. Not the easiest task and probably not worth the effort given that there is already software available to do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got hold of routeware now, what would be the best tool to use in this case?

Comment: You might want to look at the travelling salesman functionality, though I've never used RouteFinder personally so am probably not the best person to advise on it's use. I would have a read through the documentation online @ http://www.routeware.dk/routefinder/help/index.html to get an understanding of what it can do and how to do it.